# Sony A7: How to download original RAW (ARW) files through HTTP

Tags: camera, sony

The PlayMemories iOS App uses an HTTP API on the A7 that converts to JPG when you transfer images.

Here is an example of the API endpoint it uses to download a photo from the camera to a smartphone (10.0.0.1 is the A7, the phone is connected to the A7's access point using the 'Send to Smartphone' feature):

`http://10.0.0.1:60151/LRG_DSC02094.ARW?%2104%5f02%5f0591035880%5f000001%5f000001%5f000000%21http%2dget%3a%2a%3aimage%2fjpeg%3aDLNA%2eORG%5fPN%3dJPEG%5fLRG%3bDLNA%2eORG%5fCI%3d1%21%21%21%21%21`

When I decode the URL encoding it looks like this:

`http://10.0.0.1:60151/LRG_DSC02094.ARW?!04_02_0591035880_000001_000001_000000!http-get:*:image/jpeg:DLNA.ORG_PN=JPEG_LRG;DLNA.ORG_CI=1!!!!!`

I am curious if there is a way to get the original RAW (.ARW) images through the server running on 10.0.0.1:60151. If it was possible I would imagine it would involve changing "image/jpeg:DLNA.ORG_PN=JPEG_LRG;DLNA.ORG_CI=1" to a different mimetype, but I am not sure if it is possible.

**EDIT** Further investigation revealed that when you run the 'Smart Remote Control' app it provides a second HTTP API, but this one only supports transferring full resolution images on A7II and above, so A7 and A7R are not supported for image transfer at all, even though the service running on 60151 above lets you transfer full resolution JPGs, just not ARW.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as you noted above, the A7 camera does not support image transferring via the Camera Remote API.